# REGEX to match multiple conditions

Tags: java, regex

I want to find // which is:

- not preceded by a "
- not directly followed by a *
- not directly followed by span

The rest of the string should be captured as well, regardless of whether or not the last two tokens are found later in the string.

I have tried:

`//(?!span)|//(?!\\*)|(?<!\")//`

Here is an example string that I want to find it in:

`handle//Button(By.xpath("//*[@id='Page1']//span[safdsaf]"), hi);`

Comment: So for your example string you would only want to match `//Button`?

Comment: I'll work on a new expression, but your problem is the regex is read left to right and sees: `//`, `(?!span) | /`, `/`, etc.

Comment: Everything after and including `//button`

Comment: Okay so from `//Button` to the end of the string, so it shouldn't stop at the `*` or the `span`?

Comment: Correct, it should not stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like the following should work:

```
(?<!")//(?!\*|span).*
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/vXQWctfC3t